# printing each element of two ArrayLists

Tags: java, arraylist, jtextarea

I need to print each element of two `ArrayList`s.

I have something like this in mind:

```
for ((String post : Post) && (String posted : Posted)) {
    jTextArea1.append(Post + " : " +Posted "\n");   
}
```

Comment: If the elements of these two lists are always paired, they should be grouped together as member variables of a custom class you define.

Answer (score 5):

You can't use the enhanced for loop this way. Use regular for loop and obtain the current element from both `List`s by its index:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Post.size(); i++) {
    jTextArea1.append(Post.get(i) + " : " + Posted.get(i) + "\n");
}
```

This is assuming the two `List`s have the same size. If that's not the case, you should change the loop's condition to `i < Math.min(Post.size(),Posted.size())`.

Comment: wow great :D iam so dumb didnt thnk about this. 
THANK YOU VERY MUCH <3